# React app - How to show the price when the button is clicked?

Tags: reactjs, onclick

I am just learning React and I have a problem. I want the price (cena) to appear only when the "Oblicz" button is clicked.

[image]

This is the component that shows the price.

```
function CalculatorPrice(props) {

const currentPrice = props.price;

return (
    <div className='calculator__price'>
        <CalculatorBtn />
        <div className='calculator__price__box'>
            <h3 className='calculator__price__title'>Cena</h3>
            <p className='calculator__price__text'>{isNaN(currentPrice) ? <span></span> : <span>{currentPrice}</span>} zł</p>
        </div>
    </div>
);
```

}

This is the button component.

```
function CalculatorBtn() {

return (
    <div>
        <button className='calculateBtn'>Oblicz</button>
    </div>
);
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by passing state and a function to change that state to your button component which tracks when to show the price:

```
function CalculatorPrice(props) {
  const currentPrice = props.price;

  const [showPrice, setShowPrice] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setShowPrice(true);
  }

  return (
      <div className='calculator__price'>
          <CalculatorBtn showPrice={showPrice} handleClick={handleClick} />
          <div className='calculator__price__box'>
              <h3 className='calculator__price__title'>Cena</h3>
              <p className='calculator__price__text'>
                <span>{((isNaN(currentPrice) || !showPrice) ? '' : currentPrice) + zł}</span>
              </p>
          </div>
      </div>
  );
}
```

Button:

```
function CalculatorBtn(props) {
  const handleClick = props.handleClick;

  return (
      <div>
          <button className='calculateBtn' onClick={handleClick}>Oblicz</button>
      </div>
  );
}
```

You will need to add another way/button to reset your price (if you need to)

Comment: I thank you for your help, but unfortunately, the price still counts automatically - the number appears when you enter the data in the inputs. I want the number to appear only when the button is clicked.

Comment: I forgot to add the condition to the calculator component. I think it should work now

Comment: Glad it works :) I will appreciate if you can mark my answer with the green checkmark